# Ionic Lab with android intallation

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Basically i am working in Ubuntu.I created my application and set the platform android but i am getting

** ERROR**

> Command failed with exit code 2 Error output: { [CordovaError: Failed
>   to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it
>   manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update
>   your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.] name:
>   'CordovaError', message: 'Failed to find \'ANDROID_HOME\' environment
>   variable. Try setting setting it manually.\nFailed to find \'android\'
>   command in your \'PATH\'. Try update your \'PATH\' to include path to
>   valid SDK directory.', code: 0, context: undefined

Answer (score 0):

As error suggests path is not defined properly for ANDROID_HOME.

In the console(use your current location)

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/abc/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:/home/abc/Android/Sdk/tools
```

If want it to make it permanent add those lines in the ~/.bashrc file using nano or any editor.

Comment: Thank you for replying....but i have set $PATH and $ANDROID_HOME then also same problem..

Comment: I set it in ~/.bashrc file only

Comment: If they are working, there may be error with ionic lab setup.                   wget http://ionic-io-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/labs/IonicLab-linux-x64.tar.gz

Comment: set up path should be done with root privilege not the user. And try installing every thing fresh.